# How to handle DOM manipulation and state change simultaneously in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

```
<div my-directive>
<btn id="myBtn" ng-click="handleClick(mymodel.id)"><btn>
</div>

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.handleClick = function(id) {
    //Do state change here but don't access DOM here.
  }).
  directive('myDirective',function() {
    return {
      link: function (scope, element) {     
        var myBtn = angular.element(document.querySelector("#myBtn"));

       //Binding for second time! that I want to avoid. But.
        myBtn.bind('click', function(e) {
          var url = "data://adsf"; // Url is generated here because I need access to               
                                   //element to generate url.
          //Call $scope function here for handling generated url.
     });
   }
 }
});
```

In the above example, event to myBtn is bound twice, in ng-click and in bind function.
How to avoid it without any access to DOM or its manipulation inside controller?

Tl;dr
How and Where to set the state and manipulate the DOM simultaneously according to AngularJS guidelines.

Comment: you don't need the hard-coded ng-click if you use a directive

Comment: so why you need second click listener if you want to prevent it ?

Comment: I slightly updated the code, I have to pass model data in ng-click. True, I can call handleClick from the directive, but model is not accessible in directive right? I want to pass id to handleClick.

Comment: ng-click to pass id stored in the model, click binding inside directive is to access DOM.

Comment: What is the problem with 2 event handlers for the click? they seem to be independent of each other, so what is the issue?

Comment: Having two event handler for the same event does not seem right. Anyways, bind is called two times because it is linked twice, once during link and once during compile.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me why you don't like 2 event handlers. Multiple event handlers is how eventing system was designed to work, so long as they are independent, which seems to be the case here.

If, however, the event handlers are inter-dependent, then you can have the directive define its own "onClick" handler.

```
.directive("myDirective", function(){
   return {
     scope: {
        btnClicked: "&"
     },
     link: function(scope, element) {
        //...
        myBtn.bind('click', function(e) {
           // ...
           scope.btnClicked();
           // or, for example, with url param
           // scope.btnClicked({url: url});
        });
     }
   }
});
```

Then, wire the `handleClick` as follows:

```
<my-directive btn-clicked="handleClick(mymodel.id)">
```

Or, with `url` param:

```
<my-directive btn-clicked="handleClick(mymodel.id, url)">
```

Of course, it's better to name it more specifically, like "onClose" - if this is a "close" (X) button, or "onPlaybackStarted", or "urlLoaded", etc... - you get my point.